# Clojure - Recursive up function

Tags: clojure

Hi I'm kind of new to clojure and I'm trying to write a function called up that removes a pair of parentheses from each top level element of a list. If the top level element is not a list, then it is added as well. For example,

```
>(up '((1 2) (3 4)))
(1 2 3 4)

>(up '(x (y) z))
(x y z)
```

Right now, I'm having a problem with the function ending too soon if I'm trying to remove one pair of parentheses. I want to do this recursively and without the help of other functions if possible. What I have at the moment:

```
(defn up [lst]
   (if (empty? lst)
     ()
     (if (list? (first lst))
       (up (first lst))
       (cons (first lst) (up (rest lst))))))
```

I know that the problem is that I am cons-ing an empty list with the last element of a nested list which ends my function, but I can't figure out how else to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement flatten or remove just one level of parentheses? Óscar's answer below flattens the sequence completely.

Comment: I want to flatten it.

Answer (score 0):

Diego's comment seems to indicate there were other answers here, but I don't see them now, so here goes...

Your function ends too soon because, when it hits an item that is itself a list, it recursively calls `up` on that item and ignores the rest of the items in the original list. `(up (first lst))`

The minimal change to your code would be to, instead, recursively call `up` on the concatenation of that first list item and the rest of the list. `(up (concat (first lst) (rest lst)))`

Even better would be to use the existing core function `flatten` instead of `up`.

On a side note, you would generally want to achieve recursion using `recur` instead of calling `up` directly, in order to avoid a stack overflow for large input lists.